# tableviewcell does not stretch at landscape ie., orientation change

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, screen-rotation

I need a fixed header that does not go from view. I intend to keep summary of tableview below. So I started off with a UIViewController and trying to put UIView and UITableView under that.

1. In UIView I added a UIButton, UILabel but I'm running into layout constraints.
2. In UITableView, when I change orientation cell is not filling up the view. why is that? Am a newbie to ios programming. Appreciate any pointers.

Pl see the images below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like You didn't pinned all your tableview edges with superview thats why this happened..

select tableview and Pinned all edges of tableview with superview thats all..see below image

[image]